# Saved layouts disappeared from composer in QGIS 3.2.1

Tags: qgis, layouts

I made editions in the projects created in QGIS 2.1.8 using QGIS 3.2.1 and then edited it again in QGIS 2.1.8. After this I realized that all saved layouts disappeared from composers in all projects that I edited in both versions of QGIS.
Does anyone know if it is possible to restore disappeared layouts?

Answer (score 3):

QGIS projects are not backward compatible, and saving them in newer versions will make them incompatible with earlier versions.